# Firefox extension : Event listener not added to some elements

Tags: javascript, input, firefox-addon, addeventlistener, contenteditable

I developed an extension for *Firefox* with a bunch of event listeners, especially for a **predictive text** function.

It works great on most of "simple" `textarea`, `input` and `contenteditable` elements.

But it's definitely not working on some important others.

My first observation is that listeners are not applied on most of WYSIWYG editors, or on elements with already a lot of events listeners. But also on some random others.

Are websites scripts able to prevent / block adding external event listeners ?

What kind of conflict could lead to this behavior ?

What am I missing ?

This is my code : https://github.com/ANN-MB/LEIA/blob/master/extension%20firefox/leia.js

An example of absent events (mine) : https://ibb.co/SxXJFR4

This is the way I add event listeners :

```
document.querySelectorAll("input,textarea").forEach(function(x) {
  if (x.type.match(/SEARCH|TEXT|TEXTAREA/i)) {
    x.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) { 
      middot(e,this) 
    }, false);
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable],[contenteditable=true]").forEach(function(x) {
  x.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) { 
    middotCE(e,this) 
  }, false);
});
```

Same behavior with other ways to add event listeners to elements (`for` loops, without the conditional match, etc.)

**EDIT**

Based on Jaromanda X's comment, I did this. Perfectly fine with my test pages but still not on some websites. So the problem doesn't seems to be dynamically generated elements.

```
// add listeners to contenteditable elements
function addCEListeners(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) { middotCE(e,this); feminizeCE(this); }, false);
    elem.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { switcherCE(e,this) },false);
}

var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            var added_node = mutation.addedNodes[0];

            if (added_node.nodeType == 1) { // if added node is an element
                if (added_node.tagName.match(/INPUT|TEXTAREA/i)) { // if it is any kind of input or a textarea
                    if (added_node.type.match(/TEXT|TEXTAREA/i){ // if it is an input "text" or a textarea
                        added_node.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) { middot(e,this);feminize(this); }, false);
                        added_node.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { switcher(e,this) },false);
                    }
                    if (added_node.type.match(/SEARCH/i)) { // if it is an input "search"
                        added_node.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) { middot(e,this) },false);
                    }
                } else if (added_node.contentEditable == "true") { // if any other added alement is contenteditable
                    addCEListeners(added_node) 
                }
            }
        } else if (mutation.type == 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName == 'contenteditable') { // if an existing element is given a "contenteditable" attribute
            mutation.target.contentEditable == "true" && addCEListeners(mutation.target); 
        }
    }
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(document.body, {attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true});
```

**EDIT 2 :**

It seems that some of the websites on which I can observe this behavior just wipe out all `addEventListeners` except theirs with `removeEventListeners` when detecting a new listener.

Is there a way to workaround that avoiding a add/remove eventListeners war ??

**EDIT 3 :**

I found a compromise but I'm not satisfied about it. I'm listening `keyup` and `keypress` from the whole document, and if the target is a text field, I call the functions. Working for `input`s but still not for some `contenteditable` elements. Plus it's an heavy solution right ? The script is made for blind people so they use the keyboard a lot to navigate. So that's a lot of key press events to handle.

```
document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
    let targ = e.target;

    if (targ.tagName.match(/INPUT|TEXTAREA/i) &&
        targ.type.match(/SEARCH|TEXT|TEXTAREA/i)) {

        middot(e,targ);

        !elem.type.match(/SEARCH/i) && feminize(targ)

    } else if (elem.contentEditable == "true") {

        middotCE(e,targ);
        feminizeCE(targ);
    }   
})

document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    let targ = e.target;

    if (targ.tagName.match(/INPUT|TEXTAREA/i) &&
        targ.type.match(/TEXT|TEXTAREA/i)) {

        switcher(e,targ)

    } else if (targ.contentEditable == "true") {    
        switcherCE(e,targ)
    }   
})
```

Comment: One possibility is that some of textareas etc are added dynamically after your `querySelectorAll` has run, therefore, those elements wont have your listener

Comment: Well, it would explain some of them I suppose. How can I detect dynamically added elements (mostly text fields) ?

Comment: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) - but as I said, that's just one possibility - another is that there is already an (keyup in this case) event listener on the element and this listener calls [stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of (any stopPropagation method). In this case I can't workaround, right ? I'm gonna check if there is such method.

Comment: Okay, I used your MutationObserver (didn't know about this stuff, pretty useful !). Added elements are detected and targeted but still no listeners added :(